# Closing screen by bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, gnu-screen

I am trying to close a `screen(1)` by script where application is running. How could I do it? I am doing `screen -dmS name stuff_to_execute` but it creates a new one. I tried searching how to do this but found nothing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the `screen(1)` manpage:

> `-d -m`   Start screen in "detached" mode. This creates a new session but doesn't attach to it. This is useful for system startup scripts.

So I don't think `-dmS` will ever close a running `screen(1)`.

Do you want to *kill* the specified `screen(1)` instance? Or do you simply wish to force it to be detached?

If you want to kill: `screen -S name -X quit`

If you want to detach: `screen -dS name`

Comment: I want to detach it, unfortunately screen -S name -X kill does not work, this may be caused by that there is something running on the screen.

Comment: Sebi, I mis-typed my _kill_ option, I've edited it to be correct (and this time tested with _two_ `screen(1)` windows :) -- but if you just want to _detach_ the screen session, use `screen -dS name`.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use to close all screens:

```
screen -ls | grep Detached | awk '{print $1}' | cut -f1 -d'.' | while read in; do screen -X -S $in quit; done
```

It greps for the screen id and quits them all by id.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes a stubborn script holding open a screen can be killed by sending it an abort key sequence:

```
screen -X -S "script0$scriptID" stuff "^C"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
:~$ screen -list
```

There are screens on:
23308.rsamikan-3        (Monday 20 July 2015 04:42:05  IST)     (Detached)
23014.rsamikan-2        (Monday 20 July 2015 04:41:53  IST)     (Detached)
22730.rsamikan-1        (Monday 20 July 2015 04:41:44  IST)     (Detached)
16037.rsamikan-remote   (Monday 20 July 2015 02:51:37  IST)     (Attached)
4 Sockets in /var/run/screen/S-rsamikan.

I have kill and wipe the detached screen only with the following script.

```
:~$ **screen -list | grep Detached | awk '{print $1}' | while read in; do screen -X -S $in quit; done**

:~$ screen -list
```

There is a screen on:

16037.rsamikan-remote   (Monday 20 July 2015 02:51:37  IST)     (Attached)
1 Socket in /var/run/screen/S-rsamikan.